# PepareStatement using MS Access where some values come from a different table

Tags: java, mysql, ms-access, servlets

I am trying to insert data into MS Access DB using Servelts (`PreparedStatement`) and HTML form.

Can some help me on the MS Acces Insert Query. My requirement is to insert form value into MS Access and also for one of the field during `insert` has to come from a different table.

So i have it this way:

```
insert into tablename(Col1, col2, col3)
values(?,?, select col3 from diffferent_table where name=col1))
```

Can i write it this way? I have to get the value of col3 from a different table depending on the input i get for Col1

Can someone please help.

Comment: Have you tried this? It should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this would be:

```
PreparedStatement insertStatement= connection.prepareStatement("insert into tablename(col1, col2, col3) values(?,?, select col3 from different_table where name = ?)");
//Then set your parameters accordingly. As per your requirement, the 1st and last paramter should've the same value
```

If I were you, I would have done something along these lines:

```
PreparedStatement retrieveStatement= connection.prepareStatement("select col3 from diffferent_table where name=?");
PreparedStatement insertStatement= connection.prepareStatement("insert into tablename(col1, col2, col3) values(?,?, ?)");

//set the value
retrieveStatement.setXX(1,Col1);
```

I would then retrieve the value from the resultset by executing `retrieveStatement` and set this value in the `insertStatement`

The second option would help in case you need to handle specific scenario while inserting values from one table into another.
I guess you can follow this and come up with your own code